# jQuery add/remove css class on element based on selected radio

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to save a class with localstorage and based on which radio button is clicked.

In other words if I click on the second radio button, with the data-color="color2" , to add that data as a class to the .box element and save it to the localstorage. Then if I click another button, to remove all other data classes and to add only the one from the clicked button.

So far I have this but is not working.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a1d0hbuf/6/)

```
<div id="colors-list">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" id="color1" name="colors-radio" value="1" checked="checked" data-color="color1">
         <span class="color1" title="color #1"></span>
      </label> 
      <label>
         <input type="radio" id="color2" name="colors-radio" value="2" data-color="color2">
         <span class="color2" title="color #2"></span>
      </label>
      <label>
         <input type="radio" id="color3" name="colors-radio" value="3" data-color="color3">
         <span class="color3" title="color #3"></span>
      </label>
      <label>
         <input type="radio" id="color4" name="colors-radio" value="4" data-color="color4">
         <span class="color4" title="color #4"></span>  
      </label>      
   </div>
```

jquery:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
             var csscol = localStorage["activecol"];
          if (csscol) {
              $('.box').addClass(csscol);
          }
           localStorage.setItem('activecol', $(this).data('color'));        
        return false;

   $('#colors-list [type="radio"]').on("change", function() {

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.box').removeClass($(this).data('color'));
        } else {
            $('.box').addClass($(this).data('color'));
        }

    });
});
```

css:

```
.color1 {
    background: #aaaaaa;
}
.color1 {
    background: #888888;
}
.color1 {
    background: #555555;
}
.color1 {
    background: #222222;
}
#colors-list{
    padding: 80px;
}
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little messed. You have repeated classes **.color1** plus others...

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4jq5r9sk/2/).

Updated code follows:

```js
var csscol = localStorage["activecol"];
if (csscol != undefined) {
    $('.box').addClass(csscol);
}

$('#colors-list [type="radio"]').on("change", function (e) {
    var color = $(this).data('color');

    localStorage.setItem('activecol', color);

    $('.box').removeClass('color1 color2 color3 color4').addClass(color);
});
```

```css
.box.color1 {
    background: #aaaaaa;
}
.box.color2 {
    bbackground: #888888;
}
.box.color3 {
    background: #555555;
}
.box.color4 {
    background: #222222;
}
#colors-list {
    padding: 80px;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="colors-list">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="color1" name="colors-radio" value="1" checked="checked" data-color="color1">
        <span class="color1" title="color #1"></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="color2" name="colors-radio" value="2" data-color="color2">
        <span class="color2" title="color #2"></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="color3" name="colors-radio" value="3" data-color="color3">
        <span class="color3" title="color #3"></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="color4" name="colors-radio" value="4" data-color="color4">
        <span class="color4" title="color #4"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code:

First of all class names for your colors are same 'color1'. Second what does the 'return false;' do?

then the:

```
localStorage.setItem('activecol', $(this).data('color'));
```

Does nothing since '$(this)' does not point to your radio input.

Also add/remove class logic does not add/remove the right class to/from your box.

Here is what I come up with. Its general solution so number of radio buttons/colors does not change your JS logic, as bonus I added a code to restore selected input from local storage too:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let csscol = localStorage["activecol"];
    let $box = $('.box');
    //save original classes
    $box.data('initial-classes', $box.attr('class'));

    if (csscol) {
      $box.addClass(csscol);

      // Restore checkbox as well
      $('#colors-list [type="radio"][data-color="'+ csscol +'"]').attr("checked",true);
    }

   $('#colors-list [type="radio"]').on("change", function() {
        let $this = $(this);  

        if($this.is(":checked")) {
          //Replace all classes with initial box classes
          $box.attr('class', $box.data('initial-classes'));
          $box.addClass($this.data('color'));

          localStorage.setItem('activecol', $this.data('color'));  
        }

    });
});
```

Please see the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e9kjLmyz)